# AutoHotkey - Script stops working after a while

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using a simple script, all working fine as I want, but after switch a couple windows or after a while it just stops working.

```
#InstallKeybdHook
#IfWinActive ahk_exe Figma.exe

$!WheelUp::
    Send {Control down}
$^WheelUp::
    Send {WheelUp}
    SetTimer,ControlUp,-300
Return

$!WheelDown::
    Send {Control down}
$^WheelDown::
    Send {WheelDown}
    SetTimer,ControlUp,-300
Return

ControlUp:
    Send {Control up}
Return

#IfWinActive
```

Is there anything I am missing?

I'm trying to swap keys only when I'm using Figma. I want when I press ALT+mouseUp sent to the software CTLR+MouseUp, and ALT+mouseDown send CTRL+mouseDown.

Answer (score 1):

> I want when I press ALT+mouseUp sent to the software CTLR+MouseUp, and ALT+mouseDown send CTRL+mouseDown.

If this's all you need, then wouldn't a simpler code do the job? Do you have any other unspoken needs?

```
!WheelUp::SendInput, ^{WheelUp}
!WheelDown::SendInput, ^{WheelDown}
```

The timer can be interrupted by other threads, i.e. another timer subroutine or a hotkey subroutine. When we send keyboard and mouse commands fast, subroutines ControlUp that are constantly being created are constantly being interrupted by newly created timer subroutines and new hotkey subroutine. In the end, these backlogged subroutines, which are postponed running, may not send {Control up} at the timing we expect, which makes script not working as we expect.

Comment: No, that's the code I need but I tried with that code but also it stops working after a while. Maybe after I exchange windows or something it stops working. I need to reload the script to work again.

I'm just using one script with that code you've sent and still stops working :(